# Including an Excel file and call once packed into a jar

Tags: java, excel, deployment, jar

I have developed an ExcelReader/Writer program that is intended to be ran on other computers. In this program, it takes in an `excel.xls` of hard data, reads it and writes it in a formatted way to an `excel.xlsx` file, and then saves it in a directory "`CoC-Forms`".

To reduce the steps to run my program, I have included the empty `.xlsx` file that it writes to in the project. However, when exporting it to an executable jar (to run on other computers), I seem to be having trouble accessing this empty form. I know this is probably a very simple answer, but I have been stuck for over a full work day and it has completely halted my progress.

Here is a snippet of my environment. On the left is my Project directory in Intellij (CoC.xlsx is the empty form) and the highlights on the right are where I am attempting to access the file and where the error is happening respectively.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"About to look for CoC");
    //fileFrom = new File(s + "/out/production/XML Reader/CoC.xlsx");
    //fileFrom = new File("/XML Reader/out/production/XML Reader/CoC.xlsx");
    //fileFrom = new File("CoC.xlsx");
    //fileFrom = new File(ExcelWriter.class.getResource("CoC.xlsx").getPath());
    CodeSource src = ExcelWriter.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
    /*if (src != null) {
        URL url = new URL(src.getLocation(), "CoC.xlsx");
        fileFrom = new File()
        System.out.println(url);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Failed");
    } */

    fileFrom = new File(new File("."), "CoC.xlsx");
```

Comment: Please post your code in a code block instead of using a screenshot.

Comment: @lukegv Apologies, new to SO and still trying to figure out all the formats

Comment: I changed your title and the tag associated, because it looked too vague. good luck with the new one! 
PS: have you tried with the full path in your jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by having people download the whole project folder, file referencing with a ../../ from point of execution, and then going deeper into the file path to find the location at which I placed the file. Choppy, but it works and solved the problem.